# Xamarin Forms - Plugins.BLE - MvvmCross.Plugins.BLE

Tags: c#, plugins, bluetooth, xamarin.forms

I want to develop an app with Xamarin Forms which detects devices and interacts with them by bluetooth connection.

The plugin "Plugins.BLE" seems good to me for my request. I found this plugin here : https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

I did not find the plugin "Plugins.BLE" when I wanted to install it in Xamarin Studio, so I tried to use the MvvmCross.Plugins.BLE plugin. So I downloaded it and installed it in my project. A reference to MvvmCross.Platform has been installed in the same time. I set the permissions for bluetooth in the AndroidManifest.xml.

I have many problems with this plugin. In the first place, I initialized an adapter like this :

```
var adapter = Mvx.Resolve<IAdapter>();
```

I put this code in my App.xaml.cs but I got a NullReferenceException when I build.

Otherwise, when I put

```
var ble = Mvx.Resolve<IBluetoothLE>();
```

Xamarin Studio does not recognize the IBluetoothLE interface.

Maybe errors come from MvvmCross using. I don't want to use MvvmCross so if the plugin "Plugin.BLE" is available I would like to use it but I did not find it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to search for pre release. Currently we haven't released a "stable" 1.0 without the "-beta" postfix. Every package thats version have "-foo" postix are recognized as prerelease by nuget. 
The null reference exception is a typical error if you haven't referenced the platform specific package in your iOS or Android app. Running the package on a simulator can cause some problems, too. We are working on this.